# Intersection of compact sets

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, proof-explanation, examples-counterexamples

I have a brief question about Theorem 2.36 in Baby Rudin.

The theorem is as follows:

> If $\{K_\alpha\}$ is a collection of compact subsets of a metric space $X$ such that the intersection of every finite subcollection of $\{K_\alpha\}$ is nonempty, then $\bigcap K_\alpha$ is nonempty.

I actually follow Rudin's proof, but the whole theorem seems a bit counterintuitive for me.  After all, it is quite easy to draw, say, three sets, $A$, $B$ and $C$ such that $A\cap B$ is nonempty, $A\cap C$ is nonempty, $B\cap C$ is nonempty, but where $A\cap B \cap C$ is empty.  Imagine for instance you draw to circle-sets, $A$ and $B$, on top of each other, where the top of the lower circle intersect the bottom of the upper circle.  Then you draw one more set, $C$, sorta formed like a snake, where the "tail" of the snake intersect the right side of the lower circle, extends a while out, curves $180$ degrees (sort of forming a donut-shape), and then its "head" intersects the top circle on the right side (wish I could upload a picture - but hope you get the point).  Then $A\cap B$ is nonempty, $A\cap C$ is nonempty, $B\cap C$ is nonempty, but $A\cap B \cap C$ is empty.  So if $A, B, C$ are compact, wouldn't the theorem then be invalid?

If someone can explain to me what is wrong with my reasoning above, then I would be very grateful!  Is it perhaps that we here assumes that $K_\alpha$ is supposed to be a collection of inifinitely many sets?  And in my reasoning above I only use $3$ sets?

Comment: If $A \cap B \cap C$ is empty, then the condition the theorem requires doesn't hold (since $\{ A, B, C \}$ is a finite subcollection).

Comment: Is $every$ intersection of a finite subcollection of your three sets non-empty?

Comment: Qiaochu - thanks!  That's what I thought could be my mistake.  David - on my drawing, yes.

Comment: uhmm -- it's been a while, so I'm not up to date, my apologies. But what exactly are you referring to with 'Baby Rudin'? Rudin's 'Principles of Mathematical Analyis'? How did it get _that_ name?

Comment: Thomas - that's right.  I thought Baby Rudin was a pretty common nickname for the book all over the world :).

Comment: @Thomas: Yes, I don't know the history of the nickname or where it has spread, but I've heard this, and it is in comparison to Rudin's *Real and complex analysis*, which is sometimes referred to as "Papa Rudin" or "Daddy Rudin" or something similar.

Comment: @Jonas: The thing I really like about this is that quality seems to prevail (sometimes). It's, I think, 20 years, that I and my costudents decided that Rudin's books are first choice when it comes to learn Real Analysis, the basics of measure theory and functional analysis. I still own his books and won't give them away. It's a surprise (and a very pleasant one) to learn that they are still popular :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps it would help to think of an analogy with the open cover definition of compactness.  A space is compact if every open cover has a finite subcover.  However, you can easily come up with examples of compact sets that have a covering with 3 open sets, but no subcover with 2 open sets.  (Of course, trivially you can have covers with 1 set and no subcover with 0 sets.)

Compactness allows you to reduce an open cover to a finite open cover, or to check that an intersection of closed sets is nonempty by only checking that every finite intersection is nonempty (and here, it is that last **every** that is key, as Qiaochu and David pointed out in the comments).  In both cases, it is a condition that reduces infinite to finite, roughly speaking.  But this says nothing about reducing finite to smaller finite.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Jonas!  I think I get this now :)!  Much appreciated.