# Intersection of a family of compact sets having finite intersection property in a Hausdorff space

Tags: general-topology, compactness

**Problem**

> Let $\langle X,\tau\rangle$ be a Hausdorff topological space. Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a non-empty family of compact subsets of $X$ having the [finite intersection property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_intersection_property). Then prove or disprove that $\displaystyle\bigcap_{F\in\mathcal{H}} F\ne\emptyset$

So far I had been able to make only the following two observations,

- for all $F\in \mathcal{H}$, $F$ is closed (since $\langle X,\tau\rangle$ is Hausdorff).
- $\displaystyle\bigcap_{F\in\mathcal{H}} F$ is closed and hence compact.

However, I am unable to proceed any further. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(*) In general space $Y$ is compact if and only if every family of closed sets that has finite intersection property has a non-empty intersection.

---

For a proof of that see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2638547/75923).

Choose some $K\in\mathcal H$.

Let $\mathcal H_K$ denote the collection $\{K\cap H\mid H\in\mathcal H\}$ of subsets of $K$ and now focus on compact Hausdorff space $K$.

Prove that $\mathcal H_K$ has finite intersection property and is a collection of sets closed in compact set $K$.

Applying (*) it can be concluded that $\bigcap\mathcal H_K\neq\varnothing$ and consequently $\bigcap\mathcal H\neq\varnothing$.

Comment: But we do not assume that $X$ is a compact space.

Comment: @TonyS.F.  that is the reason of switching the focus to compact $K$.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $X$ is not compact, $\exists \mathcal{O} = \{O_\alpha:\alpha \in I\}$ an open cover which does not have a finite open subcover. Furthermore we can consider the collection of closed sets $\mathcal{H} = \{F_\alpha=X\backslash O_\alpha:\alpha\in I\}$. Since $\mathcal{O}$ does not have a finite open subcover, $X\backslash \bigcup\limits_{\alpha\in J} O_\alpha\neq \emptyset$ for any finite index set $J$. This implies that $\bigcap\limits_{\alpha\in J}X\backslash O_\alpha = \bigcap\limits_{\alpha\in J}F_\alpha\neq \emptyset$ for any finite index set $J$, i.e. we have the finite intersection property for $\mathcal{H}$. Since $\mathcal{O}$ is an open cover we have $\bigcup\limits_{\alpha\in I}O_\alpha = X\implies \bigcap\limits_{\alpha\in I}F_{\alpha} = \emptyset$.

Comment: But the elements of $\mathcal H$ are supposed to be compact.

Comment: @drhab you're absolutely right :\