# Intersection of uncountable monotone decreasing compact sets

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Let $C$ be a nonempty compact set. $A$ is a family of subsets of $C$, and $A$ is a totally ordered set with respect to the inclusion $\subset$.
If $A$ is countable, then the intersection of all the elements in $A$ is nonempty.
But if $A$ is uncountable, does the conclusion also hold?

Comment: If each member of $A$ is non-empty so is the intersection. Cover any member by the complements of the remaining .

Comment: I found the answer https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/88336/intersection-of-compact-sets.

Comment: There is absolutely no difference between the proof for the countable case and the one for the uncountable case.